# In SQL, how to populate number in sequence in column without alter the table structure?

Tags: sql, hana-sql-script

populating number in a sequence for a column without altering table structure--need a query

Comment: You need to try to do it yourself, show some of your work, and be specific about where you are stuck.  SO isn't a free code writing service.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change or alter the database table structure, you have limited solutions actually.

First option might be using a sequence object

```
create sequence mySequence increment by 1;
```

After you have a sequence object, you can read from this sequence whenever you need this field value

```
select mySequence.nextval from dummy;
```

Unfortunately, each read will increment the current value of the sequence.
This means if you read but did not insert the value into the table, next time you insert a new row there will be a gap in your table column.
Or if you insert two rows from two different executions, one might read the sequence first but insert value later than the other thread; then the sequence will be like 11,12,**14,13**,15

Second option is creating a database table **trigger** AFTER INSERT statement.
Then you can the max value from table column (or can store in a separate table) or from sequence, and update the column field with this sequence data